# iOS is there a way to determine if annotations are de-clustering?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation

I am using Apple's Map Kit for my app and I was wondering if there is a way to determine which annotations were declustered. For example, if there are 2 large clusters and I zoom in, is there a way to determine which annotations were removed from the cluster? I looked through all the documentation and there doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this.

Alternatively, is there a way to identify all clusters at any given point? I know there's clusterAnnotationForMemberAnnotations but that is called only when a new cluster is formed.

Comment: I understood your question but want to know why you need all the annotations in the clusters?

Comment: It has to do with my other question as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51144550/swift-obtain-visible-annotations-clusters-shown-in-map

I am trying to identify if there exists an annotation by itself (in the current view) and is not part of a cluster.